# Optimal way to chain/pipeline transforms

Tags: saxon

I've done some research on saxonica.com, Google, and Chat GPT to find the optimal way to chain/pipeline transforms without incurring serialization and parsing.  I found ways to do it with s9api, JAXP, and fn:transform().  I've found some articles implementing intermediate results as DOM, as SAX, and as XDM.  Some of the articles I found are 14 years old, so I'm not sure which is ideal now in 2023.  I'm executing Saxon within a Java Servlet running on Jetty, based on the Servlet example on saxonica.com, which caches the compiled Templates.  I don't like fn:transform(), as I don't think it can use compiled stylesheets like I can in Java; if I got this wrong, let me know (I do have static parameters).  Speed is my number one priority.  It does not have to be portable, as I will only be using Saxon.

What is the modern recommendation?

Comment: For Xslt30Transformer, see https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Xslt30Transformer.html#asDocumentDestination(net.sf.saxon.s9api.Destination)

Comment: As for `fn:transform`, it allows you to set static parameters and it allows you to use compiled SEFs for the stylesheet, but you can't do both at the same time, I think, as basically the static param values need to be known during stylesheet compilation. Anyway, I am sure Michael Kay will show up later to tell you the expert opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've left out the possibility of using a separate pipeline language such as XProc or Orbeon to orchestrate the workflow.

You've also left out the possibility of doing a sequence of transformations within a single XSLT stylesheet using the pattern

```
<xsl:variable name="phase-a-output">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="phase-a"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="phase-b-output">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$phase-a-output" mode="phase-b"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$phase-b-output" mode="phase-c"/>
```

If you're comfortable coding in Java then I would recommend using the s9api API. Create three Xslt30Transformer instances A, B, and C, and then do

```
A.applyTemplates(source,
   B.asDocumentDestination(
      C.asDocumentDestination(
         serializer)))
```

You mention that you are using static parameters. You should be aware that static parameters are applied at the time the stylesheet is compiled, which means that if you use the same stylesheet repeatedly with different values for static parameters, it's going to be recompiled each time.

I think you're right to be a little wary of fn:transform(), not so much for performance reasons as because it can be very hard to debug.

Comment: Yes, left out those.  I also found a serialization parameter for xsl:output of saxon:next-in-chain, which can also do chaining.  Thank you for your recommendation.  That is what I was looking for.

Comment: One question on s9api, that I assume is not worth a new stand-alone question: when I switch from JAXP to s9api, I'm getting stylesheet errors that EXPATH and SQL functions cannot be found.  Switching back to JAXP, it finds the functions.  All jar files are in the same places.  Do I need to do something special in setting up the processor in s9api to access these extension functions?

Comment: @lschult2, make sure you use `new Processor(true)` and have the license file on the class path. If that works for you with a single stylesheet but the problem occurs only when chaining perhaps better raise a new question with the necessary details of a minimal but complete samples to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I had `new Processor(false)`.  It worked with `new Processor(true)`.  Thank you.  I'm not 100% sure what `true` does, but it appears to turn on schema validation.  I'm not sure why I need schema validation on for s9api to find the license file.  I assume schema validation comes with some performance hit, so I'd prefer it off.  That question is likely worth a new stand-alone question.

Comment: See https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Processor.html#%3Cinit%3E(boolean): public Processor​(boolean licensedEdition) "licensedEdition - indicates whether the Processor requires features of Saxon that need a license file (that is, features not available in Saxon HE (Home Edition). If true, the method will create a Configuration appropriate to the version of the software that is running" and "If the argument is set to false, a plain Home Edition Configuration is created unconditionally"

Comment: Yep, I see it now.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Creating the three Xslt30Transformer instances A, B, and C, chaining with `asDocumentDestination()` works.  But what if I want to grab and inspect the XdmValue between each step?  I tried doing it with `XdmValue aXdm = A.applyTemplates(source);`, doing some inspection (i.e find the stylesheet to use for B), then doing `XdmValue bXdm = B.applyTemplates(aXdm);`.  But this doesn't perform the sequence normalization that `asDocumentDestination()` does.  So when the stylesheet applies templates using "/myroot", it doesn't match anything.  What's the recommended way to inspect between chain steps?

Comment: You can send the result to an `XdmDestination` (rather poorly named class) which does the normalization step, retrieving the result for inspection using `XdmDestination.getXdmNode()`. You can also send the results to both a transformer destination and an `XdmDestination` simultaneously, by use of the `TeeDestination` class.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, here's the result I have now, with all of your help.

In this example, there is no input XML, so I'm passing in `<root/>` just to get a context item so `transformer.appyTemplates()` hits something *(I could instead call a template by name, if ss1.xsl was written with named templates)*.

The XSL stylesheet name for `ss2` comes from the result of the first transform `d1`, in an `@xsl` attribute of the root element.  So that is extracted before doing the second transform.  This approach also makes it easy to inspect intermediate results when debugging, e.g. a URL param could serialize `d1` instead of `d2`.

I know I could skip `d2` and serialize it right away, but this lets me do something different by inspecting `d2` before serializing, even though I'm not doing that here.

It works brilliantly, and is very fast.

```
ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();

Processor processor = new Processor(true);

String ss1 = "ss1.xsl";
XsltCompiler c1 = processor.newXsltCompiler();
XsltExecutable s1 = c1.compile(new StreamSource(new File(ss1)));
Xslt30Transformer t1 = s1.load30();
XdmNode rootNode = processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(new StreamSource(new StringReader("<root/>")));
XdmDestination d1 = new XdmDestination();
t1.applyTemplates(rootNode, d1);
        
String ss2 = d1.getXdmNode().children().iterator().next().getAttributeValue(new QName("xsl"));
XsltCompiler c2 = processor.newXsltCompiler();
XsltExecutable s2 = c2.compile(new StreamSource(new File(ss2)));
Xslt30Transformer t2 = s2.load30();
XdmDestination d2 = new XdmDestination();
t2.setGlobalContextItem(d1.getXdmNode());
t2.applyTemplates(d1.getXdmNode(), d2);

// Optionally do something based on d2 inspection, e.g. more transforms generating d3, d4, etc.

XdmDestination xdmOut = d2;

res.setContentType("text/xml");
Serializer serializer = processor.newSerializer(out);
serializer.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "xml");
serializer.serializeXdmValue(xdmOut.getXdmNode());
```